# How can i show database list for current user with laravel passport on controller

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-passport, laravel-controller

i have a laravel app that uses laravel passport and vue.js for the front-end. Currently when i show a list from the database it shows all the elements of the table and i want it to show me only the data from the current user

I've seen that this function is made in the controller

```
public function index()
{
    $prospect = prospect::all();

    return $prospect;
}
```

In the database table i have a variable 'Salesman' that  equals to the variable 'first' of current user

do you now how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the route is inside an 'auth' middleware, you should be able to use the Auth facade, and limit your query as so:

```
public function index() {
    $prospects = Prospect::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
    return $prospects;
}
```